# An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request

Tags: c#

What this means?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502.
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> ```
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\b5d50123\4baf1c64_5780cc01\Tooltip.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\f75ac7b7\30b20097_5480cc01\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\853f18ae\b26243f5_d1d5cb01\Masterworks.Controls.Web.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\e43c5d29\51c72b28_6c74cb01\Iesi.Collections.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\911b5b42\18ea1580_6a5ecb01\Masterworks.SqlLocalization.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\a8b3bdef\4ebfce7e_6a5ecb01\Masterworks.Cryptography.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\c2317027\e86fb4e0_d341cb01\Microsoft.Practices.Web.UI.WebControls.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\48bac770\1e6c3a24_5880cc01\FoodOrder.Shell.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\d06c67e9\efbee87f_6a5ecb01\Masterworks.Controls.Web.SecurityControls.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\App_GlobalResources.xw29jesx.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\53cb1bdc\1860c5e0_d341cb01\Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\1be16282\5915bd22_5880cc01\FoodOrder.Core.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\App_global.asax.u95mrm-a.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\a1f2870f\1ecff82b_da21cb01\CSSFriendly.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\6d6af5ce\851e6028_6c74cb01\NHibernate.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\4ada28a5\5b97a426_5880cc01\FoodOrder.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\64acacfd\041c067a_6c5ecb01\Masterworks.WebControlCaptcha.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\34f09ef4\a0b2a524_5880cc01\FoodOrder.Notifications.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\02ba03eb\95a66223_5880cc01\FoodOrder.Data.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\App_Web_swohbrqr.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\24789032\78d4bce0_d341cb01\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\715b874b\ae4aa563_8186cb01\DayPilot.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\19b1cd66\ba096a28_6c74cb01\Castle.DynamicProxy2.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\aaf304a9\71a232e1_d341cb01\ManagedFusion.Rewriter.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\78131b2d\8b852f5f_695ecb01\Masterworks.Buttons.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\b24420c4\dbd4fc7e_6a5ecb01\Masterworks.ConfirmButtons.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\de089f2d\3d9d9f14_d544cb01\FredCK.FCKeditorV2.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\c9f50bf2\43a75d21_5880cc01\ProjectBase.Data.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\60b92aa4\cdb55928_6c74cb01\log4net.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\a1581848\8e7dcf0b_7ad6cb01\Masterworks.Controls.Web.Validators.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\11e54d93\e5ef9b28_6c74cb01\Antlr3.Runtime.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\a645b2ed\98baed28_6c74cb01\FluentNHibernate.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\f900ae16\b247c823_5880cc01\FoodOrder.Lib.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions.Design\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\3e6c6fbf\ed7db520_5880cc01\ProjectBase.Utils.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\1d165978\15481a25_5880cc01\FoodOrder.RestaurantModule.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\2b037192\e32e44e1_d341cb01\PostBackRitalin.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\c47bde74\1f6ad8c0_3984cb01\NHibernate.Linq.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\344c2531\5b4ffb28_6c74cb01\Castle.Core.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\0f060aeb\8eeca628_6c74cb01\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\assembly\dl3\699a6c99\5909df08_7ad6cb01\Masterworks.Utilities.DnsQuery.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\App_Web_search.master.7371103c.wkrdmiw6.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /win32res:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\7oevkkzx.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\App_Web_search.master.7371103c.wkrdmiw6.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\85135762\a89acdb6\App_Web_search.master.7371103c.wkrdmiw6.1.cs"
> ```
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5446; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means you tried opening a web page and when asp.net tried to compile on the fly as it does it couldn't build the solution. You have a build error or you need to rebuild the solution. Open the solution in Visual Studio and try to build it. If it has compile errors fix them until you can build it then try to browse to it again.

Comment: has no errors. And it works in no demo mode. Code is the same.

Comment: Check the .net version you are running is correct for the project and you are using the correct app pool?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same error, it got resolved by below steps:

1) Remove ASP.Net Temporary files (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files)

2)Clean and rebuild the solution. Make sure you set the StartUp Project in your project in solution explorer.

Comment: Just Removing ASP.Net Temporary files did it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just restart application pool (stop and start). And it works!

Answer (score 2):

I had created a new Web API project in Visual Studio 2017 and published to an IIS-hosted server which only supports `C#6` and `.NET Framework 4.5.1`.

The project had the Nuget package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` at version `2.6.1` which in its description says:

> Referencing this package will cause the project to be built using the specific version of the C# and Visual Basic compilers contained in the package, as opposed to any system installed version.
>
> This package can be used to compile code targeting any platform, but can **only be run** using the desktop **.NET 4.6+ Full Framework**.

I suppose I could have tried downgrading the Nuget package alone but I chose to create the project in Visual Studio 2015 instead, which used version `1.0.0` of this package, among changes to other Nuget packages, resulting in a successful build on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to right click on c:\windows\Temp and modify the authorizations of the IIS_IUSRS account by adding Modify, read execute, write...

Comment: There is no IIS_IUSRS account.

Comment: Don't know why this has multiple downvotes. This answer is valid and solved my problem. 1 upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Solution Explorer -> `Clean Solution` Then `Rebuild Solution`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I upgraded NuGet packages. I had to manually remove the `packages` folder and then manually select `Restore NuGet Packages` for the solution. Then everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config like namespace "...."

Answer (score 0):

I restarted app-pool, IIS. I cleared temporary files. None of them solved issue.
Finally, I restarted the PC. It works.