# Random Error "an error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request" causing compilation errors

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have an ASP.Net MVC application running on 2 production IIS servers.  There is no problem with the build or deployment.  Randomly (once every few weeks), one server will start giving compilation errors saying it can't find a DLL in ASP.Net temporary files (see screenshot).
[image: Error screenshot]

Clearing the asp.net temp files folder fixes the error, but I can't figure out why it occurs.  It's not a disk space issue, there is plenty of space.

Comment: possible duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621809/an-error-occurred-during-the-compilation-of-a-resource-required-to-service-this

Comment: possible duplicate ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817870/asp-net-strange-compilation-error/37028173

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the same, thanks.

Comment: You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis